# Getting output of `pmset -g ps` to to trigger an email via Mail.app when output includes "UPS Power"

Tags: terminal, email, automator, osx-elcapitan, piping

I've just gotten a UPS and would want notification emails whenever the UPS kicks in. I've connected the UPS via USB so OS X can monitor it via Energy Saver, but there are no other options for notifications.

I've tried installing apcupsd, but am not able to install it due to compatibility issues with OS X 10.11.1

In an effort to find a simple workaround in absence of apcupsd to accomplish this, I am looking at using `pmset -g ps` to indicate the current power status since it gives an string output indicating status as "AC Power" or "UPS Power"

I want an email to be sent whenever the output of `pmset -g ps` contains `"UPS Power"`. Not really sure if I need to pipe the output as a file or set it to the clipboard, which then can be read by the terminal in order to trigger an email via Mail.app if it contains that particular string, or if there is a simpler method via Automator to accomplish this.

Thank You!